# display selected value from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a form where user selects the category while adding the product.

When user want to edit the product, i am displaying all the previously populated values but could not able to figure out how to display the category he selected.

addproduct.php (displaying the categories from the database)- this code is working fine and can see all the categories in dropdown

```
<?php                                                                
    require'dbconn.php';
    $subject = mysql_query("select * from categories", $link);;
    while($subjectData = mysql_fetch_array($subject)){ 
    echo $subjectData['value'];?>
    <option value="<?php echo $subjectData['name'];?>"><?php echo 
    $subjectData['name'];?>
    </option>
```

In the edit product i want to display all the categories like above, but want to display the selected category in the form which i could not able to do.

editproduct.php (rough draft code) -- not working

```
<?php                                                                
        require'dbconn.php';
        $subject = mysql_query("select * from categories", $link);;
        while($subjectData = mysql_fetch_array($subject)){ 
        echo $subjectData['value'];?>
        <option select="<?php echo $cat;?>"value="<?php echo $subjectData['name'];?>"><?php echo 
        $subjectData['name'];?>
        </option>
```

$cat - category value(previously selected) pulled from database

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman: Yes i am beginner. will surely listen to your advise.  thanks

Comment: If you're just getting started on this project there's a lot going on here that could be fixed before it becomes unmaintainable. If this is a legacy project where this was all in place before you showed up, I can understand you've got constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require'dbconn.php';
    $subject = mysql_query("select * from categories", $link);;
   <option value="<?php echo $cat;?>"><?php echo $cat;?></option>
    while($subjectData = mysql_fetch_array($subject)){ 
    echo $subjectData['value'];?>
   <?php if($cat!=$subjectData['name']){?> <option value="<? 
  php echo $subjectData['name'];?>"><?php echo 
  $subjectData['name'];?>
   </option>
 <?php } ?>
```

Try using this code and please use mysqli as mysql is deprecated. previously selected category should be before while loop. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Tried the above code, selected category is displaying twice now.  To make it more clear lets say i have A, B, C as categories and user selected category B while adding the product.  Now after modifying the code like above, now in the drop down values are like B, A, B, C.  Hope i explained clearly

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your code:

1. You are using mysql functions, which are depreciated and don't even exist in the current version of PHP. Use mysqli or PDO functions.
2. The html you are generating is invalid syntax.

I'll leave the first issue to you to correct.

For the 2nd issue, all of the non-selected options in your dropdown will not have the selected attribute.
Only the selected item will have that attribute. The code below assumes that the variable $cat has the previously selected value, and each row has a 
column named 'cat'. When $cat matches the value in the column 'cat', it will add `selected='selected'` to the option.

```
<?php                                                                
require 'dbconn.php';
$subject = mysql_query("select * from categories", $link);;
while($subjectData = mysql_fetch_array($subject)){ 
    echo $subjectData['value'];
    $selected = "";
    if($cat == $subjectData['cat']) {
        $selected = "selected='selected' ";
    }
    echo "<option ".$selected."value=".$subjectData['name'].">";
    echo $subjectData['name'];
    echo "</option>\n";
}
?>
```